# Read and consume single word in C++

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I'm trying to make a configuration file for a program in c++. I want to make it so my properties are stored in a text file like this:

```
MUSIC 0.25
FX 0.25
MUTE false
```

So, I'm using ofstream like this:

```
fStream file;
file.open(route);
string read;
int value;
while(file >> read){
    if(read.compare("MUSIC")==0){
        //Here I want to replace the 0.25 with value desired
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I read the 0.25 and substitute it with my desired value?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Changed ofStream to fStream, so it supports both reading and writing

EDIT 2: Using the code the user Kerrek SB suggested:

Using input:

```
MUSIC 0.25
FX 0.25
MUSIC_MUTE false
FX_MUTE false
```

and code:

```
fStream file;
file.open(route);
string read;
string value;
bool found = false;
while(file >> read){
    if((read.compare("MUSIC_MUTE")==0) || (found==false){
        file >> read >> value; //code suggested
        if(read == "false"){
            file << "true"; // write desired value
            found=true; //stop the iteration
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

```
MUSIC 0.25
FX 0.25
MUSIC_MUTE false
FX_MUTE falsetrue
```

So it's not consuming the input neither overwriting it.

Comment: What is `ofStream`? Something you homebrewed?

Comment: I just found out that ofStream is only to _write_ so I should use fStream that supports both, my bad, will edit it

Comment: `read.compare("MUSIC")==0` --> `read == "MUSIC"`.